# Blue Screen - SnapShot restore in Compute Engine - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, boot, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I cannot restore a snapshot of an instance with Windows Server 2019.
When restoring the snapshot generated with the machine **turned on**, I get a machine that does not start and always has a **blue screen** as a return.
When restoring a snapshot generated with the machine **turned off**, everything works normally, the restored machine **boots normally**.
Serial Port = inaccessible_boot_device 0xffff google cloud platform

Answer (score 9):

There is a [restriction](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot#restrictions) in VSS enabled snapshot.

- When a VSS snapshot is taken, Windows marks the volume as read-only.
- The read-only flag must be cleared if a user want to create an instance from it.

[To work around this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot#read-only), remove the read-only flag from any new disk that you create from a VSS snapshot.

Alternatively, you can create a new disk/compute instance using [gcloud beta compute instances create --erase-windows-vss-signature](http://cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/create#--erase-windows-vss-signature)

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-3 \
--source-snapshot=snapshot-1 \
--boot-disk-size=50 \
--boot-disk-type=pd-standard \
--boot-disk-device-name=instancedisk-3 \
--erase-windows-vss-signature
```

Comment: Hi RRiovall, thank you very much for the solution.
Actually the parameter "--erase-windows-vss-signature" **solved the case**, the machine started to start normally, without a blue screen problem.
I was doing a periodic restoration test and I got a blue screen as a tectorno, now I imagine the situation of someone who has an urgent restoration.

Comment: Thank you. For me, with gcloud sdk version of 433.0.1, I need to change the command a little bit: `gcloud beta compute disks create my-disk-1 --source-snapshot=disk-snapshot-1 --size=200 --type=pd-standard --erase-windows-vss-signature`. Then manually mount the disk in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: I am surprised this flag is not described in the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot?_ga=2.206241107.-1935863053.1644247038#read-only instead they suggest to attach a disk to another VM and run some Powershell commands to clear this flag.

Comment: I cannot get it to work. Getting an "ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): May not assign arbitrary value eraseWindowsVssSignature to message Instance". My gcloud is 456.0.0

Comment: Worked for me when I created the boot drive separately as  described by @WaltyYeung.